# Why are material animations not responding?

Tags: animation, game-engine, materials, logic-bricks

First of all, I don't even know where the keyframes go when I press `I` over the material. I assumed it was on the current selected animation, but when I play it, the color does not change. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. First, change the options in the tab, *Material* - *Options* - *Object
   Color* and deactivate *Use Mist*.
2. Then, go to Timeline and place your marker in FRAME 1, go back to
   the *Object* tab change the *Object* - *Options* - *Object Color* tab (you
   will cmbios).
3. Change color or alpha according to your needs and insert a KEYFRAME
   (place the mouse over the LMB level controls and select insert 1
   keyframe).
4. Now, go to Timeline and place the marker in the frame you need in
   this case, use FRAME 2.
5. Return to the *Object* tab and see options color object, again you
   have the color or transparency adjustment you need and insert a new
   keyframe.

**Now try placing the mouse in Timeline or give play to your animation, it should work correctly.**

> Follow the gif that I made this complete step by step:

[image: Example!!!]